# Shell alias file not working after copying it into container, works after source command?

Tags: docker, alpine

I'm copying `aliases.sh` into an alpine-based container:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm-alpine AS php

COPY .docker/aliases.sh /etc/profile.d/

CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

When I log into the shell, my aliases won't work. If I run:

```
source /etc/profile
```

The suddenly start working. Maybe I need to add `source` command into my `Dockerfile` but.. it doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Unix shells usually only load files like `/etc/profile` when they are started as a login shell. Ash, which is the default shell on Alpine, also does that.

From the [ash manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ash):

> A login shell first reads commands from the files /etc/profile and .profile if they exist.

Starting the shell with `-l` should start it as a login shell and it should read `/etc/profile`.

```
ash -l
```

Comment: Thanks, I was a bit unclear in my original question. I was using the "log into container" feature of Docker Desktop, so i was not "able" to specify `ash -l`. Solved using `ENV ENV="/etc/profile"` in `Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 0):

`ENV ENV="/etc/profile"` is how I solved. Added it to the `Dockerfile`. Now despite how I log in into the container (using Docker Desktop, VS Code docker extension, etc.) I'm able to use the aliases provided by `aliases.sh`.

Comment: Could you please expand on this answer?  I am not sure what you mean, but want to have a couple of aliases set up in a dev container environment for VScode.